# Resources to start research on the SYK model, with AdS/CFT in mind

Tags: resource-recommendations, research-level, ads-cft, holographic-principle

What are the main resources to learn the SYK model, focusing more on the AdS/CFT side rather than pure condensed matter theory, assuming a comfortable background in QFT, GR, and a bit of bosonic string theory.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/299959/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36303/2451

Comment: Recent SYK review: https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.05037